# What does API Version setting do in Facebook App settings?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to [Facebook Platform Versioning](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions) there are two ways to interact with Facebook API, via versioned calls and unversioned calls.

> For APIs, once a version is no longer usable, any calls made to it will be defaulted to the next oldest usable version.

So if I make a call to v2.1 and it's no longer usable it will default to v2.6 because it is the current oldest usable version. Also, if I make a call to version v2.9 I will get a reply from v2.9 because it is available.

> An unversioned call will default to the oldest available version of the API

In this case if I make unversioned call I will also get defaulted to v2.6.

---

Taking all this into account what does the setting in the app's "Settings -> Advanced -> Upgrade Api Version -> Upgrade All Calls" do?

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Comment: Thanks, I've read that document and all I can infer from it is that "Upgrade API Calls" sets the default fallback version in case you do unversioned or expired version calls. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I figured this out myself after reading through [Graph API Version Upgrade Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) as @CBroe recommended and testing unversioned and expired version calls.

Basically what this does is it sets the minimum fallback version in case you do unversioned or expired version calls. According to documentation this setting is available a month before a *(fallback)* version upgrade.

If you do a call to a version that is still usable then this setting does not have any effect.